# Wordpress 5.2 YouTube video auto-embed in posts is not working

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed, wordpress-gutenberg

In my personal Wordpress blog (5.2), the auto-embed for videos does not work. The editor shows a spinner (very briefly), but then it shows the link to the video in the backend and the URL in plain text in the frontend instead.

I've tried changing the post in different Browsers (all failed), I tried different videos - some from vimeo (none works). When I use the iframe embed-code provided by YouTube in the HTML-editor for the post the exact same video works fine in the same post.

I've disabled all plugins and switched to the original theme, but that did not help, the auto-embed still does not work.

It seems to know its supposed to create an embed element (judged by the code it generates for the frontend), but fails to do so apparently:

```
<div>
<!-- wp:core-embed/youtube {"url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioZX_pJz-Cc","type":"video","providerNameSlug":"youtube","className":""} -->
<figure class="wp-block-embed-youtube wp-block-embed is-type-video is-provider-youtube">
<div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioZX_pJz-Cc</div>
</figure>
<!-- /wp:core-embed/youtube -->
</div>
```

I have no idea what to try next, and it's driving me nuts, so help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance and all the best,
Lucas

Comment: maybe you have some kind of browser plugin enabled that blocks requests to youtube?

Answer (score 1):

There might be multiple causes. Let me state some of them:

- you can try Youtube short URL https://youtu.be/ioZX_pJz-Cc instead. I had the same issue, using the short URL helped.
- if `echo get_the_content()` is used instead of `the_content();`, embed code might not be generated.
- sometimes plugins conflict with each other while using WP hooks. Override all conflicts in the template file: `<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ); ?>`
- obviously updating WP core and plugins to the latest version might help as well. No matter how Gutenberg is perspective, it still buggy.

Credit: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8411