# How to access Gutenberg "core-embed/youtube" with php

Tags: php, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I tried to access the embed youtube from Gutenberg in my php like this:

```
if ( $blocks[$i]['blockName'] === 'core-embed/youtube' ) {

php echo $blocks[$i]['innerHTML'];
}
```

what I get is this:

```
<figure class="wp-block-embed-youtube ...">
  <div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qm-fZNp5nCc
  </div>
  <figcaption>Dies ist ein Video</figcaption>
</figure>
```

What I expect is a full embedded video or at least just the link. I would be thank full for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56061255/6160662

Answer (score 1):

I did run into the same problem and after hours of searching for a solution I tried this and it's working ... just filter the not rendered url attribute:

```
$output = '';
$blocks = parse_blocks( $content );
foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
$output .= render_block( $block );
    if( "core-embed/youtube" === $block['blockName'] ) {
$not_embedded =  $block['attrs']['url'];
$output = str_replace( $not_embedded, wp_oembed_get($not_embedded), $output );
    }
}
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go through all embedded blocks you can just look for

```
//look if "core-embed" is part of the blockName
if ( strstr( $lookfor_embedded, 'core-embed' ) ) {
    $not_embedded =  $block['attrs']['url'];
    $output = str_replace( $not_embedded, wp_oembed_get($not_embedded), $output );
}
```

This is working for vimeo and youtube but not for tiktok (it outputs different things)